# Turn cURL into Requests

Tags: python, curl

Here is my cURL, which works:

```
curl -k -u 'user_name:password' 'https://api.instartlogic.com/xxxx/v1/cache/purge' -d '{"purge_request":{"action":"PURGE","uris": [{"match_mode":"PREFIX_LITERAL","uri_pattern":"http://www.myurl.com"}]}}' -X POST
```

I am trying to convert it to a python script using the requests library:

```
import requests
import json
from celery import task
headers = {}
auth_str = str(user_name) + ':' + str(user_passwd)
auth_str = base64.b64encode(auth_str)
auth_str = "Basic " + auth_str
headers['Authorization'] = auth_str
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
user_name = "username"
password = "password"
customer_name = "customer_name"

@task
def cache_flush(user_name=user_name, user_passwd=password, customer_name=customer_name):
    api_host = "http://api.instartlogic.com/xxxx/v1/cache/purge"

    payload = json.dumps({
        "purge_request": {
            "action": "PURGE",
            "uris": [
              {
                  "match_mode": "PREFIX_LITERAL",
                  "uri_pattern": "http://www.myurl.com"
              }
            ]
        }
     })
    re = requests.post(api_host, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
```

But I keep getting back a 404 with the content `'{"message":"No security context available.","type":"NotFound"}'` and I can't find any information about that error anywhere.

Comment: your curl request uses https, your python code uses http. Otherwise both should be equivalent.

Comment: Yeah, but changing the curl to http still works and changing the request to https still doesn't.  I thought the -k flag is equivalent to the verify=false to handle that (but I'm not sure)

Comment: ok, one difference is that requests doesn't send a content-type header when you use a string as data, while curl sends it as application/x-www-form-urlencoded, don't know if the server requires that. Try to set a content type header, or you can also try to pass your payload [as `json=` without encoding](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) it, it will be sent as application/json automatically.

Comment: Good thoughts but no go.  Updated code to reflect

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
import requests

data = '{"purge_request":{"action":"PURGE","uris": [{"match_mode":"PREFIX_LITERAL","uri_pattern":"http://www.myurl.com"}]}}'

response = requests.post('https://api.instartlogic.com/xxxx/v1/cache/purge', data=data, verify=False, auth=('user_name', 'password'))
```